# cpp function that returns value depending on the template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typename

I would like to convert the following pseudo-code into c++17 code:

```
template<class T>
char* foo(){
    if(T is a float) return "we have a float"
    if(T is a int) return "we have a int"
    if(T is a double) return "we have a double"
    return "unknown"
}
```

Such that I can use it like

```
LOGD("%s", foo<float>());
LOGD("%s" foo<double>());
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: `if constexpr` + `std::is_same_v<T,float>` etc

Comment: I phrased my question such that compile-time safety does not really matter since "unknown" is returned for unimplemented types.
Nevertheless, I was actually looking for a compile-time safe solution and both answers do that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check the types, and since you mentioned C++17, you can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), which checks the condition at compile-time, and according to the result the statement-true/false would be discarded.

```
template<class T>
const char* foo(){
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) return "we have a float";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) return "we have a int";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) return "we have a double";
    else return "unknown";
}
```

Before C++17 you can also use the *original* `if` and the condition would be checked at run-time.

BTW: The c-style string literal has the type of `const char[]` and can't be converted `char*` since C++11, so better to change the return type to `const char*`.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using 'constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)' compared to  std::is_same<float,T>::value' ?

Comment: @ConstantinGeier For simplicity. `std::is_same_v<T, float>` vs `std::is_same<T, float>::value`.

Comment: @ConstantinGeier: For this code, it doesn’t matter at all; for more complicated cases (*e.g.*, with recursion), constexpr if is more capable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a generic class to contain the message:

```
template <class T> struct message { static const char * const value; };

template <> 
constexpr const char *message<int>::value = "we have an int";

template <class T>
const char *foo() { return message<T>::value; }
```

For every new type you want to include, you need to add yet another case for your function, while with a generic class you only need to define the new message:

```
template <> 
constexpr const char *message<float>::value = "we have a float";
```

See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_mhHwI